# Send Vue.js input to Flask backend?

Tags: javascript, python, flask, vue.js

There is an interesting example on the Vue.js site that reverses a string using JS running in the browser. How can I recreate this example by passing the string to Python using Flask, reversing the string in Python, and then sending the result back to Vue - instead of doing the string reversal in the browser?

**HTML**

```
<div id="app-5">
  <p>{{ message }}</p>
  <button v-on:click="reverseMessage">Reverse Message</button>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
var app5 = new Vue({
  el: '#app-5',
  data: {
    message: 'Hello Vue.js!'
  },
  methods: {
    reverseMessage: function () {
      this.message = this.message.split('').reverse().join('')
    }
  }
})
```

Source: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/

Comment: you could use axios

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use `fetch` api or some http lib that vue uses like vue-resource but it doesn't matter.

code could look something like this

```
methods: {
    reverseMessage: function() {    
        fetch('/route', {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    'Accept': 'application/json',
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                },
                body: JSON.stringify(this.message)
            })
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => this.message = data)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It won't work as both of them are hosted on different ports, so to communicate with them you need to either use Axios or Flask cross origin or to tackle HTTP request.